# Tool to Verify Site URLs/SiteMap?

Tags: seo, url-rewriting, wget

I'm moving a site from one e-commerce software to another, and I've created URL Rewriter rules to do 301 redirects from the Old URLs to the new ones. I've tested them with a small sample of URLs, but I'm looking for some sort of tool that will let me test as many of the URLs as possible. Does anyone know of a tool that I can feed a list of URLs (or a sitemap.xml). This tool will attempt to retrieve each URL, and then report the status code for each. The result should be a list of URLs with the status code, something like this:

> www.site.com/oldurlformat1/ 301 Permanently Moved
>
> www.site.com/newurlformat1/ 200 OK
>
> www.site.com/oldurlformat2/ 301 Permanently Moved
>
> www.site.com/newurlformat2/ 200 OK

I can almost do this with wget, but getting the summary/report at the end is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html#Description) a long time ago, for a list of URLs to check and it was ok.
From the features list, the things that might help you:

> Detects and reports redirected URLs
>
> Site Map

I haven't used it since then and can't say how well the current version works, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: This looks like it will work nicely. It allows me to load a text file containing URLs, and it will check each one and report on them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Google webmaster's tools to do that.
Just sign up to this service, and submit the sitmap.
You'll have a feedback on what's OK and what's wrong.

Here is the link : https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home

Comment: Thanks for the info. The problem is that the new site isn't live, and will be on an entirely different domain. Plus, I think those tools are all about crawling a site and finding broken links, etc. The URLs I want to test will not be on the new site, since they are in the format of the old site.